# Match strings using asterisks (wildcards)

Tags: javascript

I want to test if any string in an array matchs with a particular string. However, the strings in array may contain the asterisks pattern.

```
var toTest = ["foo_*", "*foo_1", "foo_1*", "bar", "*foo"];
var toMatch = "foo_1";
```

For this sample, the result will be true because `foo_*`, `*foo_1` and `foo_1*` will match with `foo_1`, but `bar` and `*foo` won't.

I have tried to use `split` function with lodash `_.some` but it seems overcomplicated and I can't make it works consistently.

```
function isMatching() {
    return _.some(toTest , function(a) {
        return _.some(a.split("*"), function(part1, idx1) {
            return (part1.length && _.some(toMatch.split(part1), function(part2, idx2) {
                return (part2.length && idx1 == idx2);
            }));
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Can there be > 1 wildcard?  I.e `"*foo_*_bar"` ?

Comment: Not needed, no. One wildcard only

Comment: Do you, by any chance, mean that * should match all? E.g. `foo_*` should return true when tested with `foo_1`?

Comment: @LuisÁvila yes, exactly.

Answer (score 2):

To achieve expected result, use below option of using filter, indexOf and replace

```js
var toTest = ["foo_*", "*foo_1", "foo_1*", "bar", "*_foo"];
var toMatch = "foo_1";

console.log(toTest.filter(v => toMatch.indexOf(v.replace('*', '')) !== -1))
```

Comment: *_foo should be *foo and it'll appear in the list when it shouldn't.

Comment: @kemicofa, i just saw question was modified

Comment: Yes, exactly and in your array you don't have `*foo` but `*_foo`